# pod update not workd in mac, ruby error message coming

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

In my mac, when I update pod, it gives ruby error..ruby updated to latest. How to fix

[image]

```
pod update
```

Comment: Seems that your Xcode Command Line Tools are corrupted / out-of-date. Use `xcode-select --install` to install/update the tools, which contains `xcrun`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xcode Command Line Tools are missing or corrupted.

Install / Re-install Xcode Command Line Tools via the following command in Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

which contains the tool `xcrun`.